# How to let github automatically track changes of an overleaf project?

Tags: github, version-control, latex

I'm wondering if it is possible to let github automatically track changes when I make changes to an overleaf project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [Overleaf documentation](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_do_I_connect_an_Overleaf_project_with_a_repo_on_GitHub,_GitLab_or_BitBucket%3F), you might consider adding  an Overleaf Project as a Git Submodule

> Each project on Overleaf gets its own git repo, but if you want to organise several such projects into one git repo on GitHub, you can add the repo for each project as a git submodule in the usual way.
>   You can then push and pull each submodule repository to/from Overleaf individually and still have them collected together as submodules in the project on GitHub.

Then a `git submodule update --remote` would automatically update your local repo with the latest from that submmodule.